# How to access a attribute in terraform

Tags: list, object, terraform, attributes

I have a local object created as:

```
       first   = {
          sns  = "first-rzv3-sns-prod"
          s3   = "first-rzv3-s3-prod"
          sqs  = "first-rzv3-sqs-prod"
        }
      second   = {
          s3   = "second-rzv3-s3-prod"
          ec2  = "second-rzv3-ec2-prod"
        }
```

variable `user = [first, second]`

I'm trying to create a resource with its name based on the `username`. For example

```
resource "create_s3_bucket" "example" {
  count = length(user)
  name  = local.hashed_names_prod."${var.user[count.index]}".s3
}
```

`name` should be `"first-rzv3-s3-prod"` and `"second-rzv3-s3-prod"`

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resource can be simplified with the `for_each` meta-argument such that `var.user` becomes unnecessary and everything generally becomes cleaner:

```
resource "create_s3_bucket" "example" {
  for_each = local.hashed_names_prod
  name     = each.value.s3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create two resources. One with the name first-rzv3-s3-prod and the second one with second-rzv3-s3-prod.

```
resource "create_s3_bucket" "example" {
  count = length(user)
  name  = lookup(local.user[count.index], "s3")
}
```

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/lookup